# How to create mesh/plane with desired number of width and length segments?

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, mesh, plane

I have an array of 40000 floats that designate height level on a map. I would like to create a mesh/plane in OpenGL ES 2.0 to assign each vertex in this mesh a height value from this array so that they create a map of terrain.

Problem arise when I need to figure out the **indices** - which vertex connects to which one in order to create a triangle mesh.

How can I do that since I do not know how to assign those indices?

So far my data looks like this where each row represents

```
vertices[i*3] + ", " + vertices[i*3+1] + ", " + vertices[i*3+2]

0.0, 0.6091919, 0.0 
1.0, 0.60876465, 0.0 
2.0, 0.6079712, 0.0 
3.0, 0.60684204, 0.0 
4.0, 0.60546875, 0.0 
5.0, 0.60391235, 0.0 
6.0, 0.6022949, 0.0 
7.0, 0.600708, 0.0 
8.0, 0.5991516, 0.0 
9.0, 0.59765625, 0.0 
....
0.0, 0.5961914, 1.0
1.0, 0.5947571, 1.0
2.0, 0.5933533, 1.0
3.0, 0.59191895, 1.0
4.0, 0.5904541, 1.0
```

Ok so I have managed to load it to `FloatBuffer` like

```
FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * BYTESPERFLOAT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(vertices).position(0);
```

But how can I proceed (if the way I did this so far is corect) ?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to derive this is to draw a grid of vertices, put some indices on it, and figure out what sequence of indices is needed to draw the grid with OpenGL primitives.

Let's say we have a n x n grid of vertices, which describes a grid of (n - 1) x (n - 1) squares. For a quick sketch with n = 4, and with indices assigned to each vertex:

```
12--13---14---15
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
8----9---10---11
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
4----5----6----7
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
0----1----2----3
```

These 9 squares can be drawn with 3 triangle strips, with a strip for each row. The index sequence for the 3 strips is:

```
4, 0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3
8, 4, 9, 5, 10, 6, 11, 7
12, 8, 13, 9, 14, 10, 15, 11
```

Generalizing this to a general value for n, this results in n - 1 strips with 2 * n indices each. These indices can be generated in sequence with a couple of nested loops:

```
GLushort* idxA = new GLushort[(n - 1) * n * 2];
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j) {
    for (k = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        idxA[i++] = (j + 1) * n + k;
        idxA[i++] = j * n + k;
    }
}
```

Then to draw, after all the buffers are filled, and all the vertex state set up:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j) {
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 2 * n, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (char*)0 + j * n * 2);
}
```

This can be done with a single draw call when using primitive restart, but this feature is not available in ES 2.0. It's also possible to do something similar by repeating vertices if having just a single draw call is critical.

Comment: Can't I fill the vertices buffer and then call `glDrawArray`?

Comment: Not without repeating vertices. If you look at the sketch and corresponding index sequences, all but the first and last row of vertices are used for two strips. Using indices allows you to use the same vertex multiple times without repeating the vertex attributes in the vertex buffer. For a large grid, you save almost 50% of the memory (and corresponding bandwidth) this way.